# How can I find the data lineage from a ".item" file in Talend Studio?

Tags: python, java, xml, parsing, talend

I am trying to get the data lineage of all the tables in our database automatically through a script. I found the .item files in talend which I guess are the xml files that describe the flow of a talend job.

How would I parse the file effectively so I get each data source (from a tOracleInput or tFileExcelInput) that went into inserting into an output table (tOracleOutput)?

I've tried reading the file and trying to wrap my head around a way to do it but I am blanking.